# MPI: Sending 2D Vector Row by Row

Tags: c++, multithreading, multidimensional-array, vector, mpi

I am trying to send each row of a 2D vector using MPI_Isend(). I then need to receive that row and store it in a 1D vector. Am I missing something? This is what I currently have...

```
vector<vector<char>> board;
for (int i = 1; i <= num_procs - 1; i++)
    {
        MPI_Isend(&theData, 3, MPI_INT, i, 43, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req);
        cout << "Sent Data From Process " << my_proc << " to Process: " << i << endl;
        for (auto j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        {
            MPI_Isend(&board[j], board[j].size(), MPI_CHAR, i, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req);
            cout << "Sent Row #" << j << " Config From Process " << my_proc << " to Process #" << i << endl;
        }
    }
```

.
.
.

```
 vector<vector<char>> localAnsBoard;
    for (int i = 1; i <= num_procs - 1; i++)
    {
        vector<vector<char>> localBoard;
        for (auto j = 0; j < rowsLocal; j++)
        {
            vector<char> charArr;
            charArr.resize(colsLocal);
            cout << "HERE" << endl;
            /// GETTING HUNG UP HERE
            MPI_Recv(&charArr, charArr.size(), MPI_CHAR, MASTERPROC, j, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat);
            localBoard[j] = charArr;
            charArr.clear();
        }
```

Comment: did you first receive the 3 bytes? do you `MPI_Waitall()`? if you are still stuck, please edit your question with a [mcve]

Comment: I don't think `MPI_Isend(&board[j]` is correct. Should be `board[j].data()` or `&( board[j][0] )`. Likewise `MPI_Recv(&charArr` is wrong: your receiving into the C++ object, not its data.